# New Macbook Pro Retina Spinning Wheel Then Complete Freeze

Tags: macos, freeze, crash, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

I checked the console and this message was repeating before crashing, although I am not certain it caused either the spinning wheel or the freeze.

12/11/13 8:45:56.106 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[186]: (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[81003]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13

[image]

This is the third time I've had to hard kill a brand new macbook retina.  I am considering going back to the old upgradable macbook.

Any ideas on what could be causing the crash?

Furthermore, what is wondershare?  I didn't specifically install it.  What applications or extensions would have installed wondershare?

Answer (score 0):

The wondershare page says that it only supports OSX 10.6 and 10.7.  The new MacBook presumably came with 10.9, so your problem likely lies therein.

http://www.wondershare.com/mac-android-manager/reference.html

You should probably ask about newer OSX support at their site.